# How to exclude a specific file from a folder in a ssis?

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, ssis

I have excel folder with multiple excel files in them, now I had a package the loaded 2 excel files every time, now one file is added to the folder and my package is picking that file, but I don’t need that file to be loaded with the 2 excel file.

Excel source file structure

Mortgage 25-12 sale.xlsx

Mortgage 24-33 employee.xlsx

Mortgage 21-23-67 loan.xlsx

Now I don’t need my package to pick up

Mortgage 21-23-67 loan.xlsx.

Please help thanks.

Comment: You will need to add some code to your question before people can begin to help you. SO is not a code writing service, we can help you work through your problem but not do it for you.

Comment: @jacob I did tried to write a code to read the file and also created a Boolean value to the result and used it for branching the package but that seems like it was not working, I just need ideas to implement. This was my approach. Thank you

Comment: A quick solution would be to make a file system task to move the "wrong" files to a different location before processing the "right" ones.

Comment: how your "package is picking that file"? What component/task do you use?

Comment: @jacob well that would be a great solution except my boss don’t want me to move them, I already asked. Is there any other way tho?

Comment: @Benzi you mean the whole package set up? Well I have nested for each loop that is set up to edo enumerator and file enumerator, which is set up to fully qualified

Comment: But how does package know to exclude `Mortgage 21-23-67 loan.xlsx` from processing. What is the business rule? Is the presence of "loan" in the file name the signifier?

Comment: @billinkc that’s what I wanted to know, if I can exclude that file.

Comment: The question is: how should SSIS know what to exclude?

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop to loop on all files.

Start your object inside foreach with an expression Task. Set a boolean variable called test = @filename == "Mortgage 21-23-67 loan.xlsx" ? true : false

Next, add your next object (usually a data flow).

Connect the object and set the precedence constraint to expression @test = false

The loop will jump to the next file if it is the bad file or continue on if it is any other file.